# Sort array of objects in typescript - element implicty has any type

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting, types

I'm trying to sort an array of objects within a function, however the function receives the key as a parameter, so it's unknown:

```
export interface ProductsList {
   id: boolean
   nome: string
   qtde: number
   valor: number
   valorTotal: number
}

const exampleFn = (productsData: ProductsList[], order: string) => {
   if (order !== 'id' && order !== 'nome') {
        productsData.sort((a, b) => b[order] - a[order])
   }
}
```

I'm getting this error with `order`:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'ProductsList'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'ProductsList'
```

I've tried to set an `index signature` to `order`, but without success.

What can it be?

Comment: What are the acceptable values of `order`?  It's not an arbitrary string, but specifically those keys of `ProductsList` that have a number-valued property, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXQLDN), right?  If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: @jcalz that's right, the value are the same as the keys.

Comment: subtracting `boolean` or `string` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Okay, I'll write up an answer when I get the chance (unless someone else gets here first)

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler in my code I have a verification step to check the string and the boolean key. I'll update the question

Comment: To reiterate, [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question; replace images with the text.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Your question may be closed if you don't do so.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I just saw that. I didn't know that rule. It won't happen again. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since substracting string or boolean makes no sense, you should use `keyof` and an `exclude` :

```
export interface ProductsList {
   id: boolean
   nome: string
   qtde: number
   valor: number
   valorTotal: number
}

const exampleFn = (productsData: ProductsList[], order: Exclude<keyof ProductsList, 'id'| 'nome'>) => {
   productsData.sort((a, b) => {
       const c = a[order]
       return b[order] - a[order]
       })
}
```

---

edit :
With the key check, you can also skip the `exclude` !

```
const exampleFn = (productsData: ProductsList[], order: keyof ProductsList) => {
   if (order !== 'id' && order !== 'nome') {
      productsData.sort((a, b) => {
         const c = a[order]
         return b[order] - a[order]
      })
   }
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgBSggBMBXbGAZwBkFL4BvAWACg52FiAuOAIwggAbYJiSt2cJBAC2wHvSjIA5uPYBHGMTmTS03mlVwAbpkHQeSXfqiGTZqABUIMUxasGWAX1atsEJPRwoJjSYMIAYkhwALxwABRgRGQUlAAimC48hCTkVLT0ANoAugA0cNBaUDwAoiDYgqRaADwA1sAAnhDoBEm5NHQwZQDknEMAPnBDUrJDAHwAlDGzcMxs7Ik5KekuAHSU0DBxcZhlvIvRy6sS134B8NgxcJgFFWhFhtdQwDCkUFG8LyglSKcAAtE9AcCPhJPPNWN4WL5-IFgqEIkgAEyPBK9LYZTBZXF5AbFMqvKpwNqdbrZZLE+jnS6GBDdOLkuAAQmisRGxCGcAAZALykC0JzuZNpsAhosrtc4Bs6Wl8XsDkcTnxGStoTdkfdHs9ye81vL2F8fn8+JC3mCIUadbDDAjPEA)